# How to resume Android Activity programmatically from background

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent, android-activity

Situation:

1. Let's say I have currently working launched application Activity A.
2. After some time I am pressing "Home" button. Application A goes to background.
3. At this time, I am starting to use another app B - youtube for example or etc.
4. Something happens (doesn't matter what in this context, let's say timer finished calculating time) in the application A which currently is minimized to background.
5. On the event occurrence, application A activity automatically resumes from background.

Question:

How to accomplish step 5? Basically I need to know how to resume application from background programmatically.

I tried to launch intent to "restart" my application activity but it didn't worked:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            context.startActivity(intent);
```

My manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.taxti"
    android:versionCode="43"
    android:versionName="1.5.3" >     

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="13"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.taxti.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.taxti.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />       
    <permission android:name="com.taxti.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
                android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.taxti.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />     
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />  
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"        
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="com.taxti.Globals"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.taxti.InitialActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
            android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.taxti.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
            android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".MainActivityForegroundService" />

        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net`enter code here`.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />                
        </intent-filter>

       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />     
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_BUTTON" />     
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />           
            <data android:scheme="tel" />
       </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="xxxx" />             
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >   
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />               
                <category android:name="com.taxti" />
            </intent-filter>

        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: you need to call Context.startActivity()

Comment: register a broadcast receiver to listen for the specified event to occur .. you can use alarm manager to trigger time based events..

Comment: And how to resume application activity when I catch that event?

Comment: you need to call Context.startActivity()

Comment: pskink, can you explain in more detail?

Comment: the only way to bring up your Activity to front is to call Context.startActivity(Intent)

Comment: Look at my edited question. I tried to do something like you suggest but it didn't worked. Maybe I should use different intent parameters?

Comment: where do you call `context.startActivity(notificationIntent);` from?

Comment: In simple method where I catch my event occurrence. This method is not in any broadcast receiver. Should I call intent from broadcast receiver necessary?

Comment: and whats at the logcat when you startActivity()?

Comment: Nothing happens. It just prints my custom log message which is placed after intent launching code.

Comment: are you sure you are not calling startActivity) from MainActvity ?

Comment: From MainActivity. It's the only one class in my application.

Comment: ok, so onStart()/onResume() is called or not?

Comment: if you are doing critical long-running work then you should just use an `IntentService`.

Comment: onResume() is not called when I try to fire intent.

Comment: add Log.d in onResume() and onPause() of your MainActivity and watch the logcat what happens

Comment: pskink, so I added. Nothing happens when I try to resume my activity.

Comment: and you "resume" you activity after onPause()/onStop() was called?

Comment: Yes. After successful calls.

Comment: Just add the code, where you tried to restart your activity. "In simple method" ..where...

Comment: What version of Android are you using? It looks like this is an Android-version specific problem.

Comment: See my answer and the interesting discussion with @pskink in the comments

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to bring your app to the foreground, you must call `startActivity()` from another context (either a `Service` or a `BroadcastReceiver`). Just calling `startActivity()` from within an `Activity` won't bring your app to the foreground.

You don't need the ACTION and CATEGORY in your `Intent`, but you do need to set `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`.

Comment: "Just calling startActivity() from within an Activity won't bring your app to the foreground." you don't need another Context, you can use Activity's Context with no problems

Comment: @pskink Using Activity's Context to start an Activity will work, but it will NOT bring the task to the foreground if it is in the background. This is OP's problem.

Comment: it will bring, just tested that

Comment: @pskink interesting. Because I've also just tested this and it doesn't work. What Android version are you using? I've tested on 4.3

Comment: 4.4 i just called postDelayed(Runnable, int) in onPause where Runnable.run just calls startActivity and onResune got called, btw where in the docs are the statements saying what you say?

Comment: @pskink nowhere is this specific behaviour documented. But I've just seen it with my own 2 eyes. I would be interested to see your entire test project.

Comment: its just http://pastebin.com/mdD8ZwMm add some Log.d in onResume and press Home button after launching Activity

Comment: @pskink Very interesting! Thanks for your comments. This is dependent on Android version. It looks like this behaviour has been "fixed" as of 4.4. I just tested with 5.0 and it also works as you described. Then I tested with 4.0.4 and with 2.2 and on those devices it works as I describe (also on 4.3).

Comment: Thank you, David. Your proposed solution worked for me.

Comment: I had to use Service context. Activity context didn't worked for me. At least on Android 4.2.2.

Comment: To make things more confusing, it works as desired when I install the app using Eclipse, but does not work when I Export the SAME code to a file and install from the file.  targetSdkVersion="21" and I have updated the SDK on my dev system to 24.

Comment: Just using application context works (5.1.1, 7.0) for me, even within an activity.

Comment: opening activity from background by new intent it is creating another activity over the previous activity. I want to open the same activity what ever was the state

Answer (score 3):

If your activities are on different tasks, you can use this to bring the activity's task to foreground:

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE); 
activityManager.moveTaskToFront(getTaskId(), ActivityManager.MOVE_TASK_NO_USER_ACTION);
```

You would need `android.permission.REORDER_TASKS` in order to do so. It works even in Android M, however getting an intent from a service works better in some cases.

Comment: Straight respect me general. You answer is the only answer that make sense here, that actually answered the question. Everyone else gave us stone when banana was what was asked for. You know, it proves there lack of knowledge about Android and UI programs in general. Anyhow, what is left now is to handle case when the Activity is closed. moveTaskToFront() doesnt return whethor or not the operation succeeded. However I see where I can check if the taskId is in the list of running task. Or come to think of it, maybe getTaskId returns error if the activity is closed.

Answer (score 2):

David Wasser answer helped to solve my problem.

My Activity is running in a foreground `Service` so I had to call `startActivity()` method from that `Service` context.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
mServiceContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

To Resume application from background programmatically will

> Make your activity FOREGROUND, User's current activity in BACKGROUND. **User's work is GONE**

This is not right behavior from user perspective. Additionally, if we resume activity programmatically, the activity lifecycle will be broken. The activity states will be lost.

**Alternative :**

You can provide `NOTIFICATION` when your timer, task (anything) is complete in background. If user is interested in checking your activity then he/she can check from NOTIFICATION **without interrupting current work**

Comment: User's work is not GONE. The current Activity will be paused and put in the background. In general, the user can return to that Activity and it will be in exactly the same state as it was before. Nothing is lost. Your statement about broken lifecycle is also incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Just establish a Service, doing whatever you want it to in the background. Or even better: Do something in the background, listen to it with a listener, bind a Service as soon as the event you waited for occurs (timer etc). 
Now that you are in the Service, you just call the Activity that should be on foreground like you would from anywhere else:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MyService.this, MyActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
MyService.this.startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Why the r@$$ cl@@t cant I get a good answer. I search so many stack overflow threads. I already have an Activity object that I have been using. I dont want to restart a new Activity. All I want to do is bring this old Activity to the fore. If I was using win32 api this would be super simple.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it I think is via an IntentService. It works this way too, and it's probably the easiest way. So the sequence is: register a receiver in the Activity (in onCreate) to listen for the event you want, then when the receiver gets the event, it launches an IntentService the standard way and this in turn starts the Activity.
This way it will put the app in front of other apps, both active and hidden ones. (But this should be used with caution. Normally the user won't like another app popping up in front of the one he's working with, except if there's a very good reason for it.)
On my KitKat device (4.4.x), I tested it and I can bring the app to front by calling startActivity from a receiver in the Activity **only if there is no other app open**, that is my app is hidden under the home screen. Then it will come on top. If another app is open, even if it's also hidden (but in front of my app; I actually didn't test to see what happens if both apps are hidden and mine is in front, but that's not very important), then it won't come on top if started from within the same Activity. So to make it always pop up you need to use an IntentService (or another way but this is as far as I know the simplest one).