# Bring activity to front like launcher do

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I had Global FloatButton,when it pressed, it should bring Activity A to front (which is already running).
I try:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ApplicationContext,A.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
ApplicationContext.startActivity(intent);
```

it work with activity open very slow, and lag 3s or more.

But when I press my app icon in launcher, it open quickly.

Why and How Launcher can do it?

Comment: I  read Luncher source code,it seem use FLAG:`FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED`, so I try it, but no help,still lag.

Comment: Where is this code running? In the same application? In a different application?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29766270/how-to-resume-android-activity-programmatically-from-background