# Android: How to hide or close topmost activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

In my app, I need to start the built-in camera application using the action [INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore#INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA). The reason of this action is that in this case, I can use the **Pro camera mode**, like manual ISO, exposure time, etc., while using the action [ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) this is not possible (at least for the builtin camera app for my Samsung Galaxy S20+ device)

Using the broadcast receiver intent filter [ACTION_NEW_PICTURE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera#ACTION_NEW_PICTURE) I am also able to catch the URI of the photo taken.

What I need is to hide the built-in camera Activity from the broadcast receiver's **OnReceive** method, once the photo was taken. What I tried so far is that I called my Activity from OnReceive by specifying the intent action flags FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT and FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP this way (a C# language snippet, but almost identical to Java):

```
public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.MakeText(context, $"Data1: {intent.DataString}", ToastLength.Short).Show();

    var path = Path.Combine(context.CacheDir.AbsolutePath, $"Photo_{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMMdd_HHmmss")}.jpg");
    try {
        // copy the photo to app cache dir
        using (var outs = File.Create(path)) {
            using (var ins = context.ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(intent.Data)) {
                ins.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                ins.CopyTo(outs);
            }
        }
        
        var a = Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.CurrentActivity;
        var tvInfo = a.FindViewById<AppCompatTextView>(Resource.Id.tvInfo);
        tvInfo.Append("Picture was taken and saved to:");
        tvInfo.Append($"{path}{SysEnv.NewLine}{SysEnv.NewLine}");

        // hide the builtin camera's Activity by brining my Activity to top
        var i = new Intent(context, typeof(MainActivity)).SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ReorderToFront | ActivityFlags.SingleTop);
        a.StartActivity(i);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.MakeText(context, $"Error: {ex.Message}", ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }
}
```

Here is how I start the camera:

```
var btnTake = FindViewById<AppCompatButton>(Resource.Id.btnTake);
btnTake.Click += (s, e) => {
    var i = new Intent(MediaStore.IntentActionStillImageCamera);
    var r = i.ResolveActivity(this.PackageManager);
    if (r != null) {
        StartActivity(i);
    }
};
```

The problem with the above is that it works only on the first attempt, which means I click on my app's button, the built-in camera starts. When I take a picture, the picture is saved and copied to my app's cache dir, the built-in camera's Activity disappears and my Activity appears.
But on the second attempt, my activity does not appear and the bulti-in camera's Activity stays on top.
Any idea, how to hide or close the built-in camera's Activity?

Comment: I think `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` with `SINGLE_TOP` should work fine . You do not need `ReorderToFront` here if the task Stack is same . Can u add the Intent's code you using to open camera ?

Comment: @ADM updated the post.

Comment: "The reason of this action is that in this case, I can use the Pro camera mode, like manual ISO, exposure time, etc., while using the action ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE this is not possible" -- the behavior of either of those `Intent` actions is up to the implementation of the camera app. There are hundreds of camera apps. "Using the broadcast receiver intent filter ACTION_NEW_PICTURE I am also able to catch the URI of the photo taken." -- the behavior of a camera app when it takes a picture is up to the camera app (e.g., does it send that broadcast?). There are hundreds of camera apps.

Comment: @ADM tried CLEAR_TOP with SINGLE_TOP but in that case my activity does not appear at all.

Comment: @CommonsWare I don't care other devices and other camera apps. I would like to make it work only on my device ;-)
The only thing I need to hide somehow the camera app, once a photo was taken.

Comment: When you launch the camera app, do you know if the camera `Activity` is running in your task or in a separate task? To check this launch the camera app and then use `adb shell dumpsys activity activities` and you should be able to see which task the camera app is running in.

Comment: @DavidWasser not sure but I think when I launch the camera, it's in different task, 
https://i.imgur.com/VH4INYk.png

Comment: please post the entire content of both tasks, I can't tell from this snippet.

Comment: @DavidWasser so the content for my app: https://i.imgur.com/8VFSzwg.png and the content for builtin camera app: https://i.imgur.com/qXzMJ9E.png unfortunately the entire contents are too long but hope this is enough.

Comment: Basically you don't need to bring your `Activity` to the front, as your `Activity` is already at the front of your app's task. What you need to do instead is bring your app's task to the foreground. You could try using a launch `Intent` in your broadcast receiver's `onReceive()`, like this: `var i = PackageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("your.package.name")`. Try this and let me know

Comment: @DavidWasser so I tried following: _activity.StartActivity(_activity.PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage(_activity.PackageName)); but unfortunately it does not work, the builtin camera's activity is still the topmost.

Comment: You cannot call `startActivity()` from the activities `Context` (here your `_activity`. In this case you should try using the `BroadcastReceiver`s `Context` (here your variable `context`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29766270/how-to-resume-android-activity-programmatically-from-background/29769255#29769255

Comment: In fact, looking again at your code, it looks like that may be the root of your problem (using wrong `Context` to call `startActivity()`.

Comment: @DavidWasser since it still doesn't work, let me share my full test app (it's actually very short): https://pastebin.com/xDjnxaZb and here is how it behaves on my Samsung device: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DIC2DQUsw92vz0qS2coaEAQ6v7WN1kmi/view?usp=sharing as you can see, I have to manually go back to my app, after the picture was taken.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244718/discussion-between-ladislav-and-david-wasser).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @DavidWasser finally it works!!!

Solution is to add a new *dummy* activity calling *Finish()* from its *OnCreate()* and finally call following from broadcast receiver's *OnReceive()*:

```
var i = new Intent(context, typeof(Dummy));
context.StartActivity(i);
```