# Bring back activity to the top in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, flags

I develop android application with launch mode "Single_instance". I want to run an external application from my activity, and bring back my activity to the screen. I'm using Intent.startActivity to run the application, but i'm unable to automatically go back to my activity, and keep external app running in the background. Is there any way to use some flag, to achive this?

I tried to use FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP and  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, to run external app and put it into the background, but my app doesn't go back to top.

Comment: Not sure what you try to achieve, but just of the top of my head, I think `startActivityForResult` may be what you are looking for. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result

Comment: This seems to be working fine. 
val intent = packageManager
.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.apps.youtube.music")
startActivity(intent)

Also wrap it in try catch and put the queries packages in manifest

Comment: I've got my own application with one activity and launchmode = singleInstance defined in the androidManifest. I want to launch another application (not mine), put it in the background and bring my application back to te foreground. That is not what i am looking for

Answer (score 0):

To do this you'll need to do the following:

- Launch the external app using `startActivity()`. This will put the external app in front of your app.
- Start some kind of timer (post delayed `Runnable` to `Handler` or use `AlarmManager` or something like that) that will wait a certain period of time, enough so that the external app has a chance to start and cover your app.
- When the timer expires, it should send a local broadcast `Intent` to a `BroadcastReceiver` that you create.
- The `BroadcastReceiver` should then call `startActivity()` with a "launch `Intent`" (you can get one by calling `PackageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage()` for your app. This should bring your app back to the foreground in whatever state it was in.

I have found that this will only work if you call `startActivity()` from a `BroadcastReceiver` or `Service` `Context`, and **not** from an `Activity` `Context` (which is why the extra step of involving the `BroadcastReceiver`. see. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29769255/769265 and the comment thread for more info on this problem.

There may be problems with this in modern Android versions, as there are strict limitations of how/when code running in the background can launch activities (this is to prevent background processes from disrupting the user). If this doesn't work you probably won't be able to do it at all.

I wrote this off the top of my head and hope that it is understandable.